# Unhandled exception in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

im getting the following error issue `throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event`
Here is my Controler.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
router.post('/api/sendMail', async (req,res) => {
    console.log("yes")
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my index.js

```
const cont = require('./controllers/Controler');

app.use(cont);

 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1286:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1334:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1421:7)
    at Function.listen (/Users/user/folder/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/folder/server.js:24:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1313:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
```

Im not sure what im missing but im gettng unhandled error isssue.

Comment: Some process is using port 5000

Comment: Try changing the port you bind to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use try/catch:

```
try {
    app.use(cont);
} catch(er) {
    console.log(er);
}
```

Also note that port `5000` is already in use (`EADDRINUSE`) - try changing your port to something else.

Comment: What's the point of catching the error if you throw it again in the catch block?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like something already uses **5000** port.

If you use *nix based OS, you can get list of processes like this:

```cmd
netstat -tulpn | grep 5000
```

and then, kill particular process:

```
kill -9 PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running your app using a different port or kill the process in the current port `5000`

To kill a task in windows

```
//get process running in port 5000

netstat -ano | findstr :5000 

//enter your pid and force kill
//replace <pID> with your process id

taskkill /PID <pID> /F
```